# Loading image for ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am new to ajax. Studied on w3 schools. Now i can bring load a part in the website. But when the loading is going to happen i want to show the user a loading image there. I searched in stackoverflow. Found some questions also but they are using some other types of ajax using which is beyond my knowledge.

Here is my code

```
<script>
 function loadXMLDoc(a)
  {
     var xmlhttp;
     var temp = "myname.php?id=" + a;


     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
             xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
     else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
           xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
           xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                 document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
   xmlhttp.open("GET",temp,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }
</script>



<h2>AJAX</h2>
  <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc('1')">Request 1</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc('2')">Request 2</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc('3')">Request 3</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

If someone can give me an example or link according to my coding that would help.

Comment: Are you able to use an Ajax framework like jQuery? Otherwise, could you add an response example?

Comment: jQuery is suggested to initiate ajax request for it is platform compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `<img>` element that is hidden to begin with, then when the ajax is called, show it, and when completed, hide it.

```
<script>
 function loadXMLDoc(a)
  {
     var xmlhttp;
     var temp = "myname.php?id=" + a;

     // show the loading image
     document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "";

     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
             xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
     else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
           xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
           xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                 // hide the loading image
                 document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";

                 document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
   xmlhttp.open("GET",temp,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }
</script>



<h2>AJAX</h2>

<img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading..." id="loading" style="display:none;" />

  <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc('1')">Request 1</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc('2')">Request 2</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc('3')">Request 3</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

For future reference, the [Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) docs are a good resource for plain Javascript ajax.

Answer (score 1):

1) add a loading animation image (img tag) in the HTML document and place it where you want to display, but you hide it with CSS by setting `display: none`

2) before your xmlhttp.send(), show the image by setting the image `display: ''`

3) in the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` callback function, hide the image again to indicate the loading is finished.